# Java Window Translucency on Linux

Tags: java, linux, swing, translucency

Using Java 7 window translucency on Windows XP SP3, Vista, 7, 8 and Mac OS X Mountain Lion works great.  However, on Linux I cannot get it to work properly.

Using the tutorial found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/trans_shaped_windows.html), specifically the *GradientTranslucentWindow* example, it **seems** to work great.  But if you change the color to something other than white (the only change I made was set R to 0 in the example code), the frame does not composite correctly:

[image: See this comparison]

The `isWindowTranslucencySupported` method returns true for `PERPIXEL_TRANSLUCENT`.  I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 32bit with Compiz composite manager with the Composite plugin turned on.

Questions:

1. What can I do to get this to work? Is it a Linux setting that needs to be changed, a java code change, or what?
2. Is anyone else having this problem? Java 7 has been out for some time now, but I can't find anyone else having this problem.  There are some bug reports in the Java bug database, but they are all "fixed".  I have submitted a bug to the Java bug database, but it has yet to appear on the external database.
3. I'm running Ubuntu under Oracle VirtualBox. Could this be the problem? Sadly, I do not have a machine to install Linux on, so can someone else that is running a non-vm linux try this? **EDIT** I have the guest add-ons installed.

Comment: This might be an issue with the Linux video driver. Try installing the VirtualBox Guest Additions in Linux if you haven't already done so.

Comment: I have often found that Ubuntu video on VirtualBox is less than perfect, even with Guest Additions. Try it on Wubi: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer

Comment: I have the guest add-ons installed, sorry meant to specify that.

Comment: @NickJ I was really hoping someone who is already running a non-vm'd Linux would try this out.  I really don't want to install another OS just to find out its broken.  But if it comes to it I guess thats what I'll have to do.  Another question I might add is: What distro. of Linux would be good to try on Oracle VirtualBox that might support this? I've also tried the Mint distro, but I think this is basically Ubuntu with some extra GUI tools.

Comment: that's why I suggested Wubi - it installs Ubuntu as if it were a Windows app, so you don't need another machine.

Comment: @NickJ if you want to put that as an answer I will accept it.

Findings: I bit the bullet and installed Ubuntu using Wubi and tested the Oracle Translucent window after fighting getting OpenJDK to update to 7.  The end result: It works!  So VirtualBox was definitely the problem.  However, I now have another problem which I'll post under another topic as its a bit different.

Comment: New problem posted here [Java Window Translucency Animation Flicker on Linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15704947/java-window-translucency-animation-flicker-on-linux)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VirtualBox was indeed the issue (even with guest add-ons).  Running a non-vm'ed Ubuntu with proprietary graphics card drivers allows the sample to work as expected.