# Java Window Translucency Animation Flicker on Linux

Tags: java, linux, swing, translucency

I'm trying to do animation in Java with a translucent JFrame.  I have modified the demo code from the Oracle Java Tutorials [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/trans_shaped_windows.html).  Specifically the GradientTranslucentWindowDemo.

The following code works great in Windows XP SP3 up to 8 and Mac OS X Mountain Lion and even in Linux *mostly*.  **The problem in Linux, and what I need help with, is the animation is flickering.**

I'm running Ubuntu Linux 12.04 LTS 64bit with nVidia drivers, Metacity and Compiz.  PERPIXEL_TRANSLUCENT reports true and is working well.

Is there something I'm missing in the following code or is there something on the Linux side I need to change?  I tried setDoubleBuffered(true) on the JPanel, but it did not remove the flickering.

Please reference my code changes to the Demo below:

```
import static java.awt.GraphicsDevice.WindowTranslucency.PERPIXEL_TRANSLUCENT;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GradientPaint;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GraphicsDevice;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Paint;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class GradientTranslucentWindowDemo extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    private Timer timer = new Timer(100, this);

    private double percentage = 0.0;

    private JPanel surface = new JPanel() {
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            if (g instanceof Graphics2D) {

                final int R = 0;
                final int G = 240;
                final int B = 240;

                Paint p =
                    new GradientPaint(0.0f, 0.0f, new Color(R, G, B, 0),
                        0.0f, getHeight(), new Color(R, G, B, 255), false);
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
                // CHANGE 1
                // Clear the previous graphics using a completely transparent fill
                g2d.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
                g2d.clearRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
                g2d.setPaint(p);
                // CHANGE 2
                // Only do a gradient fill for the current percentage of the width
                g2d.fillRect(0, 0, (int)Math.ceil(getWidth() * percentage), getHeight());
            }
        }
    };

    public GradientTranslucentWindowDemo() {
        super("GradientTranslucentWindow");

        setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
        setSize(new Dimension(300,200));
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // CHANGE 3
        // I thought this might remove the flicker, nope
        this.surface.setDoubleBuffered(true);

        // CHANGE 4
        // This seems to be required or the g2d.clearRect doesn't do anything
        this.surface.setOpaque(false);
        setContentPane(this.surface);
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        add(new JButton("I am a Button"));
    }

    // CHANGE 5
    // On each tick of the timer increment the percentage until its
    // more than one and always repaint
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        this.percentage += 0.05;
        if (this.percentage > 1.0) {
            this.percentage = 0.0;
        }
        this.surface.repaint();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Determine what the GraphicsDevice can support.
        GraphicsEnvironment ge = 
            GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        GraphicsDevice gd = ge.getDefaultScreenDevice();
        boolean isPerPixelTranslucencySupported = 
            gd.isWindowTranslucencySupported(PERPIXEL_TRANSLUCENT);

        //If translucent windows aren't supported, exit.
        if (!isPerPixelTranslucencySupported) {
            System.out.println(
                "Per-pixel translucency is not supported");
                System.exit(0);
        }

        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);

        // Create the GUI on the event-dispatching thread
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                GradientTranslucentWindowDemo gtw = new GradientTranslucentWindowDemo();

                // Display the window.
                gtw.setVisible(true);

                // CHANGE 6
                // Wait until the window is visible to start the timer
                gtw.timer.start();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 1:**
Removing the translucency and choosing a black background fixes the flicker problem.  The flicker is most certainly related to having a translucent window.  I also noticed that the flicker becomes worse as the window is enlarged.

**UPDATE 2:**
The line `this.surface.setOpaque(false);` is what is causing the problem.  If this is commented out, the animation does not flicker and there is translucency.  *However, upon each iteration of the animation it blends with the previous paint* (its not clearing the contents before repainting).  Doing `g2d.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));` and `g2d.clearRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());` does nothing unless `this.surface.setOpaque(false);` is set.  It's almost like this line disables double buffering on linux.

*Having a translucent window **is** a requirement.*

Comment: The implementations of translucency on win32, osx, and X11 (linux) are all entirely different, so solving a problem on one is not likely to translate in any way to the others.  Can you get a native program with translucency to perform the same or similar operation without flicker?  If not, the problem is likely in your window manager/display manager settings or in the manager itself and not in Java per se.