# How to create transluent window in Java swing?

Tags: java, swing

I work with java and I want to make a translucent window (like a black with 80% alpha). The basis of my code is those in the following post: [How to make a transparent JFrame but keep everything else the same?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14927980/how-to-make-a-transparent-jframe-but-keep-everything-else-the-same)

The problem is that when I run my program, the window is translucent but as you may see on the following picture, the background color (magenta) appears only on the text, not on the white.
[image]
Even worse, when I choose a black with transparency `Color(0,0,0,125)` as drawing color, nothing appears on the screen.

Here is what I have so far :

```
public class DssWindow extends JFrame
{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2455172975892566000L;

    /**
     * 
     */
    public DssWindow()
    {
        super("My frame");

        setUndecorated(true);   
        setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
        setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel()
        {
            @Override
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
            {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                if(!(g instanceof Graphics2D))
                {
                    return;
                }
                Graphics2D gr = (Graphics2D)g.create();
                gr.setColor(new Color(255,0,255,200));
                gr.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
            }
        };
        contentPane.setOpaque(false);
        Dimension screen = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        contentPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(screen.width,screen.height));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        pack();
    }
}
```

Do someone knows/has a clue of what is the problem ?
I am working on Linux (may this is a part of the answer).

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a transparent JFrame but keep everything else the same?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14927980/how-to-make-a-transparent-jframe-but-keep-everything-else-the-same)

Comment: That is not a duplicate. I used this post to make my program. It is another problem I have.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, my problem is stated here: [Java Window Translucency on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15658589/java-window-translucency-on-linux)
Graphics drivers seems to be the cause of this behaviour.